# SSRS migration with Same Name and Moving of Reporting Files

Tags: sql-server, migration, windows-server, reporting, ssrs-2019

This is will be my first SSRS migration and please bear with me if some points don’t make any sense.

I need to migrate the Reporting server but need to keep the same name so that the reporting URL don’t change.

Sources

Server A – Has the database and the reporting databases

Server B   only has the reporting server installed.

Destination

Server C- New SQL Server will be installed with all the databases

Server D will have the reporting server installed.

Below is a summary

•   Backup SSRS databases on source server
•   Backup Encryption Key on source server
•   Restore SSRS databases on target server
•   Restore Encryption Key on target server
•   Remove old server name from the Keys table on the target server

My confusion lies with the

1. What if I want the new server (Server C and Server D) to have the same name of Server A and Server B hence my reporting Web Service URL and the Web Portal URL don’t change.

   ```
        http://ServerB/Reports
        http://ServerB/ReportServer
   ```

My thought process was Rename Server A and Server B before migration and name Server C and Server D with the old name of Server A and Server B.

After that the Web Service URL and the Web Portal URL will pick up the default name which will be the old one. Please correct me if I am wrong and is there any thing else that I need to be aware of which might break the reporting

2. After the migration do we need to move the rds files from the old server to the new server as well and since the names are the same so do we still need to modify the data sources?

Answer (score 0):

answer to your questions:

1. after migration rename the *server B* to something else and then add a **DNS alias** to the *Server D* to match the *Server B* old name
2. you don't have to move **RDL** files becuase they are included in the Reporting server database restored on server C. About data sources you have two paths:

   - rename the *Server A* and then ad a **DNS alias** to the *Server C* that match the server A old name
   - edit each **Data Source Connections String** to point to the *Server C*. in this case yo have also to enter the username and passoword again (in case of fixed logins and not Windows authentication)

If the password are known and the Data Sources aren't too many I would prefer the second path

Comment: My concern is if I add a DNS Alias  on Server C with the old name of Server A will that show up on the Report Configuration Manager on the upper left pane for Server C (SERVERA\SSRS)  or it will show as SERVERC\SSRS in that case the Webservice URL and the WEBPORTAL URL will show as http://ServerC/ReportServer and http://ServiceC/Reports instead of http://ServerA/ReportServer and http://ServiceA/Reports which I want to show

Comment: If you mean the URL, it appear as ServerC/reports.
If you mean the SSRS website title you can customize it (site settings)

Comment: Sorry I mean if I add a DNS Alias on Server C with the old name of Server A will that show up on the Report Configuration Manager on the upper left pane for Server C (SERVERA\SSRS) or it will show as SERVERA\SSRS

Comment: it will show only inside the connection string of the data sources